# How to loop through/with await axios?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, async-await, axios

I have a problem looping through Ides then push the results to the array above, it throws out this Error: "Request failed with status code 404"
but if I removed the loop i t works correctly

```
export default class GetPlayersPerMatch {
    constructor(numPlayers) {

        this.numPlayers = numPlayers;
        this.allPlayersMatchesArr = [];

    }
    async getResultsPerMatch() {
        try {
            const proxy = 'http://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/'

            for (let i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
                const resPerMatch = await axios(`${proxy}https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/element-summary/${i}/`)
                this.playerData = resPerMatch.data
                console.log(this.playerData)
                this.allPlayersMatchesArr.push(this.playerData)
            }
            console.log(this.allPlayersMatchesArr) 

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If you're saying `${proxy}https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/element-summary/` works but `${proxy}https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/element-summary/${i}/`doesn't, then doesn't that mean you should not pass in the `i` path?

Comment: Do you have that route set up? and do element-summary/1 through element-summary/500 exist? otherwise you will get 404s for the ones that dont exist

Comment: I figured it out, thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. How sure are you there are 500 pages to look at?
2. Restruct your try-catch so that you keep on sending requests instead
   of returning on any fails
3. When you say "if i remove the loop it works" you mean that
   `/api/element-summary/1/` exists, but your loop/requests might get a
   404 on index 15 or 123 or 468...

Try it like this and let us know:

```
export default class GetPlayersPerMatch {
    constructor(numPlayers) {

        this.numPlayers = numPlayers;
        this.allPlayersMatchesArr = [];

    }
    async getResultsPerMatch() {
        const proxy = 'http://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';

        for (let i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
            try {
                const resPerMatch = await axios(`${proxy}https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/element-summary/${i}/`);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        this.playerData = resPerMatch.data;
        console.log(this.playerData);
        this.allPlayersMatchesArr.push(this.playerData);
        }
        console.log(this.allPlayersMatchesArr);        
    }
}
```

Comment: although this is really robust solution and kind of good practice to do so, but you can start your loop from i=1 because i checked the link manually and it was /0/ that made this problem.

Comment: I used 500 to check they are 567 actually :D
the problem was i = 0 although there was no ID 0.
thank you so much, it works

Comment: Good to know, have fun!